# how to create buttons for webservice apis?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, api, button

Lets say we have some webservice API which we want to expose in form of a button (something like facebook's like/ twitter's tweet buttons). I am not sure what goes behind these buttons.

I would like the button to first authenticate with my service

If authenticated the user should click the button which should be able to call a webservice.

Would love to get insights in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy from client side of view, webservice can provide you only with data.

Usuall scenario can work as following:

1. there is a button on page
2. user clicks the button
3. ajax call to webservice is made
4. webservice returns some data (f.e. current time)´
5. javascript have to display this data to user now

Hope this helps